# Get a date of birth from a given id number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to retrieve date of birth from a given id number. Below is what I have tried using substring.

```
 handleDOB = () => {
    const { idNumber } = this.state;
    if (idNumber !== '') {
      const day = Number(idNumber.substring(4, 6));
      const month = Number(idNumber.substring(2, 4));
      const year = Number(19 + idNumber.substring(0, 2));
      const dob = year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
      console.log(day);
      console.log(month);
      console.log(year);
      console.log(dob);
      return dob;
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what happened when you try the above?

Comment: It does work but looking for a better solution. Because if someone was born in 1895, my solution won't work and when the month start with 05

Comment: Hm.. If you are concerned with that, then the easiest way would be to store the full year in the state? such as `1985...`

Comment: oh okay cool, if I have an id number like 760312.... It does not include a 0,  it returns a dob of 1976/3/12. How can I fix that.

Comment: Do check my answer! Think it will be easier for both of us if I write my comments as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: Do mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarise my comments in this answer:

1) A safer way of storing the year within the `idNumber` state would be to store the entire 4 digits, such as `1985.....`. This will prevent any confusion, i.e differentiating between `1885` and `1985`.

2) When it comes to appending the leading `0`, you can use the [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method. This will ensure that only single digit months, such as March (`3`), will be formatted as `03`

```js
const formatMonth = (month, figures) =>(month.toString()).padStart(2, '0')

console.log(formatMonth(5, 2));
console.log(formatMonth(11, 2));
```